# Seventy Seven Sevens

Tags: code-golf, sequence

Given a number `n` and an upper limit `l` list the numbers that can be created by multiplying two or more numbers consisting of **only sevens** of length `n` or less that are less than `l`. [A161145](http://oeis.org/A161145) is close to this challenge, however, you will NOT be including the 7, 77, 777, 7777, 77777, etc..

## Examples

**`n=anything, l<49` would result in:**

```
[]
```

**`n=1, l=49` would result in:**

```
7*7=49

f(1,49)=[49]
```

**`n=1, l=343` would result in:**

```
7*7   =49
7*7*7 =343

f(1,343)=[49,343]
```

**`n=2,l=6000` would result in:**

```
7*7    =49
7*7*7  =343
7*7*7*7=2401
7*77   =539
7*7*77 =3773
77*77  =5929

f(2,6000)=[49,343,539,2401,3773,5929]
```

**`n=3, l=604000` would result in:**

```
[49, 343, 539, 2401, 3773, 5439, 5929, 16807, 26411, 38073, 41503, 59829, 117649, 184877, 266511, 290521, 418803, 456533, 603729]
```

Etc...

## Rules

1. You **do not** have to output intermediate steps, this was done for clarity.
2. Output can be as an array or separated by any character (even newlines).
3. Output must be in numerical order, lowest to highest.
4. To make the title relevant, highest `n` that must be handled is `n=77` (if you can't handle that high, note why - language restrictions are acceptable, laziness is not). This limitation is to hinder those looking to build the entire superset in memory.
5. If TIO cannot run `n=77` for your code, explain what specs were required to achieve `n=77`.
6. For a product to be valid it must consist of at least 2 numbers.
7. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) lowest byte-count will be deemed victorious.
8. You may choose the list to contain items less than `l` or less than/equal to `l`.
9. **BONUS**: If your code is exactly 77 bytes, kudos from me; worthless, I know.

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing "list the numbers that can be created by multiplying two or more numbers consisting of only sevens of length `n` or less that are less than `l`"

Comment: Is it acceptable to have some numbers output more than once?

Comment: Rule 5 is pretty pointless, will any code run given `n=77` and `l=7**7**7`, for example?

Comment: Can we assume that the result will not be empty?

Comment: @JonathanAllan true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 19 bytes

```
L7×1¸ì©IF®âPD²‹Ïê®K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#ATAAz///TDfDlzHCuMOswqlJN3ptw65Gwq7DolBEwrLigLnDj8Oqwq5L//83Nwo2MDQwMDA)

**Explanation**

Very inefficient. TIO link performs `ceil(l^(1/7))` iterations instead of the `l` iterations used in the golfed version to easier test large testcases.

```
L7×                   # create the list ['7', '77', '777' ...] 
                      # with the final item having n 7's 
   1¸ì©               # prepend a 1 and store a copy in register
       IF             # l times do:
         ®â           # cartesian product between current list and the list in register 
           P          # product of each sublist
            D²‹Ï      # keep only numbers smaller than l
                ê     # remove duplicates and sort
                 ®K   # remove 1, 7, 77, 777 ... from the list
```

Comment: `$L7×‚˜` - tried to get 5 bytes, couldn't.

Comment: @carusocomputing: Yeah, I feel like 6 bytes is too much, but I really can't see a shorter way. I was hoping you'd school me with a shorter way ;)

Comment: I was thinking `.p` or `.s` too, but even those seem longer. I accidentally hit 'refresh' on the TIO page with my example implementation instead of run, deleted it from existence. I think it was 26 though.

Comment: @carusocomputing: That's why you should always press the link button regularly. Don't loose anything by refreshing or rebooting the computer. A bit annoying to loose history though :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>21</s> <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
R7ẋḌµ;ŒċP€⁹f€FµÐLḟ
```

Note that the output doesn't match the OP's. I've left a comment.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@x9k/nBX98MdPYe2Wh@ddKQ74FHTmkeNO9OAlNuhrYcn@DzcMf/////G/80MTAwMDAA)

#### How it works

```
R7ẋḌµ;ŒċP€⁹f€FµÐLḟ  Main link. Left argument: n. Right argument: l

R                   Range; yield [1, ..., n].
 7ẋ                 Times; yield [[7], ..., [7] * n].
   Ḍ                Undecimal; yield s := [7, 77, ...].
    µ         µÐL   Begin a new chain with argument s and call the chain between 
                    until the results no longer chain.
                    Return the last unique result.
      Œċ            Combinations; return all unordered pairs in integers in the
                    return value.
     ;              Concatenate the return value and its pairs.
        P€          Take the product of each individual integer and each pair in
                    the result.
          ⁹f€       Filter each; for each j in [1, ..., l], intersect [j] with the
                    array of products. The result is sorted and contains no 
                    duplicates.
                 ḟ  Filterfalse; remove the elements of s from the result.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>116</s> <s>113</s> 109 bytes

```python
n,l=input()
r=t={1}
exec't|={10**n/9*7};n-=n>1;r=r|{x*y for x in r for y in t if l/x/y};'*l
print sorted(r-t)
```

Note that TIO doesn't have enough memory for the last test case.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#HcZLCoMwEADQfU4xO3VQErtoKWG8TBshEEaZTiFBc/b081av8Zgo8v7WfjBCSsdcTcjh0en5vUNke8db9TwRL7MXkvPIWGDdBDJEBvm3/KoQV0g221J9h8nsElnhtYmGZy@TDq1dRrg65z4)

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>103</s> 101 bytes

Takes input in currying syntax `(n)(l)`.

```js
n=>l=>(a=[],g=(n,m,p,i)=>(p>l||g(n,m,(a[i>1?p:a]=p)*m,-~i),--n?g(n,m+7,p,i):a.filter(n=>n)))(n,'7',1)
```

#### Test cases

The last test case may take a few seconds to complete.

```js
let f =

n=>l=>(a=[],g=(n,m,p,i)=>(p>l||g(n,m,(a[i>1?p:a]=p)*m,-~i),--n?g(n,m+7,p,i):a.filter(n=>n)))(n,'7',1)

console.log(f(1)(49))
console.log(f(1)(343))
console.log(f(2)(6000))
console.log(f(3)(604000))
```

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <s>89</s> 86 bytes

A recursive solution.

-3 bytes by remembering that anything times 0 is 0.

```ruby
f=->n,l,b=1{n*l>0?(f[n,l/k=eval(?7*n),b*k]+f[n-1,l,b]+(b>1&&l>=k ?[k*b]:[])).sort: []}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#HY3BCgIhFADvfcU7ibquKUWBoH6ISKywG4vmLildom836zoMM23Ro8kssaDlO9NkhMWL6@AY9fyaErZXmgkLNPqh81H@VD/gYCRCyegI1kUavHKeEF62Z1Xg/Kf1Ami4z7Xwsqe18se0A1J1u62HHf4H305wEWchxBc)

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 142 Bytes

```
$r=[];for([,$n,$l]=$argv;$n--;)f($v[]=$z.=7);function f($t){global$v,$l,$r;while($c=$t*$v[+$i++])$l<$c?:f($c)&$r[$c]=$c;}sort($r);print_r($r);
```

-5 Bytes removing `$r=[];` and replace `sort($r);` with `@sort($r);`

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a65d4abd194ccf6032ce3764f4b027fe469d491e)

Expanded

A recursive function make all permutations including the limit

```
$r=[];
for([,$n,$l]=$argv;$n--;)
  f($v[]=$z.=7);
function f($t){
    global$v,$l,$r;
    while($c=$t*$v[+$i++])
      $l<$c?:f($c)&$r[$c]=$c;
}
sort($r);
print_r($r);
```

PHP, 145 Bytes

```
for([,$n,$l]=$argv;$n;)$t[]=str_pad(7,$n--,7);for(;$l>=$i+=49;$v>1?:$u[]=$r)for($v=$i,$r=!$c=0;$d=$t[$c];)$v%$d?$c++:($v/=$d)&$r*=$d;print_r($u);
```

Expanded

a loop till including the limit
check every value that is divisible by 49

```
for([,$n,$l]=$argv;$n;)
  $t[]=str_pad(7,$n--,7);
for(;$l>=$v=$i+=49;$v>1?:$u[]=$r)
  for($r=!$c=0;$d=$t[$c];)
    $v%$d?$c++:($v/=$d)&$r*=$d;
print_r($u);
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4546b26d83b5fff5d384b0dc7a579e2fdbfd5757)

a few bytes more and an associative array can be created
key the number and as value an array of the used sevens

```
for([,$n,$l]=$argv;$n;)
  $t[]=str_pad(7,$n--,7);
for(;$l>=$v=$i+=49;$v>1?:$u[array_product($r)]=$r)
  for($r=[],$c=0;$d=$t[$c];)
    $v%$d?$c++:($v/=$d)&$r[]=$d;
print_r($u);
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ee6891be780577cbf373848c4b2dca782ff0ce7e)

Comment: `while($c=$t*$v[+$i++])$l<$c?f($c)&$r[$c]=$c;` saves 3 bytes; but it should be `$l<=$c`. `$r?sort($r)&print_r($r):0;` instead of `$r=[];` saves one.

Comment: `$z.=7;` is 5 bytes shorter than `$z=$z*10+7;`.

Comment: and `@` is another 4 bytes shorter than `$r?...:0;`. (Thanks @Christoph)

Comment: @Titus Why should it be `$l<=$c` ? It seems yesterday was not my day for the `$z.=7` and the additional 2 Bytes that  I have found. I am thinking first over your other two suggestions.  You miss the `:` in the while loop

Comment: I´ve asked the OP to clarify. In the description he talks about results `that are less than l`, in his examples they `are less than or equal`. Depending on the clarification, `$c>$l||...`/`$c>$l?:...` or `$c<$l&&...` are shortest.

Comment: @Titus you may choose either, as people have already done so both ways. This is valid.

Comment: Jörg this would be 137 if You actually removed the `$r=[];`. ;-) `f($v[]=...)` is a great find! And it´d be nice to put the function definition in front.

Comment: @Titus I know that is can be 137 if I remove the `$r=[]` but I will not work with `@` And your version is shorter and I could not reach your byte count. I am happy that I found a solution without using a function. Why is `f($v[]=...)` a great find? And If it is you should add it to the tips for PHP

Comment: Yours is a lot faster. Mine takes 1.7 seconds to complete the last example while yours does it in 1/8 ms. I know, that´s not the objective in codegolf; but it´s well worth to mention.

Comment: @Titus Now I see what you mean and I have also tested my second approach. Normally I prefer Performance and avoid all Error reports but it is codegolf

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>128 125 130 129 127</s> 123 bytes

will work up to 22 `7`s but will round larger values (7**23 is floating point on a 64 bit machine).

3 bytes saved by Jörg, 3 by me, <s>5 4</s> 1 added to avoid warning for empty results.

```php
for([,$c,$z]=$argv,$n=$c+1;$c<$z;$p<$z&&$r[$p]=$p)for($b=$c+=$p=1;$b|0;$b/=$n)$p*=str_pad(7,$b%$n,7);@sort($r);print_r($r);
```

takes input from command line arguments; run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f2b1f71dc5e9e1eb56c7478c639c126edcd1f3ef).

**breakdown**

```php
for([,$c,$z]=$argv,$n=$c+1;         # $z=L, $n=N+1
    $c<$z;                          # loop $c from N to L-1:
    $p<$z&&$r[$p]=$p                    # 2. if product is < L, add to array
)                                       #    (key=val to avoid duplicates)
    for($b=$c+=$p=1;$b|0;$b/=$n)        # 1. loop $b through ++$c as base-N+1 number
        $p*=str_pad(7,$b%$n,7);             # take each base-N+1 digit as length
                                            # for a streak of 7s as factor
        // (str_pad is 1 byte shorter than str_repeat and saves 3 by ensuring positive $p)
@sort($r);                          # sort array (muted to avoid warning for empty result)
print_r($r);                        # print array
```

Comment: `for([,$c,$z]=$argv,$n=1+$c;$c<$z;` instead of `for($n=1+$c=$argv[1];$c<$z=$argv[2];`

Comment: Use `@` instead of `$r&&` to suppress the warning? `$p<$z&&$r[$p]=$p`

Comment: I just noticed it should be `$p>$z?:$r[$p]=$p` from example `n=1, l=343` it is clear that `l` should be included. Therefore no savings there when using `$p>$z||$r[$p]=$p` or `$p>$z?:$r[$p]=$p`.

Comment: @Christoph I asked the OP to clarify. Thanks for reminding me of `@`; will edit when the OP replies.

Comment: @Christoph both seem to be ok; and it doesn´t really matter wether `$p>$z||` or `$p<$z&&`. I´ll stick with the description.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 22 bytes

```
JsM._*\7Eu@s*LR+JGJSQJ

JsM._*\7E
        E               second input
     *\7                repeat "7" as many times as the above
   ._                   all prefixes of above
 sM                     convert each to integer
J                       store list as J

         u@s*LR+JGJSQJ
         u              repeat the following until results not unique
                     J  starting from G = J
                        at each iteration, G is the current value
               +JG      append G to J
                  J     J
            *LR         multiply the elements of the above two, vectorizing each
           s            flatten list
          @        SQ   intersect with [1,2,3,...,first input]
                        this takes elements from [1,2,3,...,first input] and
                        check if each element is in the previous list
                        which ensures the result is sorted and unique
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JsM._%2a%5C7Eu%40s%2aLR%2BJGJSQJ&input=6000%0A2&debug=0)

### Specs

- Input: `l[newline]n`
- Output: `array containing the sorted result`

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 28 bytes

```
h>.ḋ{p~c×ᵐ{=h7&l}ᵐobt≤~t?∧!}
```

There's a lot of scope for improvement in the language itself, here; quite a few things I wrote look like they'd be obviously improvable with some changes to the language's design. This is the shortest way I've found with the current version. I may well make some suggestions for Brachylog which would make this program more efficient, shorter, and more readable.

Very, very slow; TIO times out even on the simplest possible nontrivial answer, so there's not much point in providing a TIO link. I've verified this program by running it locally.

This is a function (not a full program), whose output is a generator (as opposed to a list). Add `.w⊥` to the end of the function if you want to see all outputs, rather than just the first. (Note that this doesn't really matter in practice, because as the program is too slow for TIO anyway, you have to run it locally, and the local Brachylog interpreter runs in a REPL which can describe a generator just fine.)

### Explanation

```
h>.ḋ{p~c×ᵐ{=h7&l}ᵐobt≤~t?∧!}
  .                           The desired output is
h>                            a number less than the first input
   ḋ p                        such that taking its prime factors in some order,
      ~c                      partitioning them,
        ×ᵐ                    and taking the product of each partition
          {     }ᵐ            produces a number for which each digit
           =h7                is composed only of 7s
              &l              and for which the lengths of those numbers
                  o           are in sorted order
                    t         and the last element
                   b          (which is not also the first element)
                     ≤        is less than or equal to
                      ~t?     the last input.
                         ∧    (Delete an unwanted implicit constraint.)
   ḋ{                     !}  Output each number only once.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 108

```bash
seq -f3o%gp $2|dc|sed -r "/0|1{$1}/d;s/./&7/g;s/1//g;s/2/*/g;/[*]/!d;s/^/a=7/;s/$/;if(a<=$2)a;/"|bc|sort -un
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#NY5BDoIwEEX3nmJsqlGSOi0QiVYS72E0qbQgG6oUV9az40DibN7Ln8zP1L6HwYWhMsFB2wFTkB/YhCzPiCnspZQkGUk@qQbrF0AT3ABCAP@fz6GrHn4uBMbP7DgG9wJRZ37VPIGn0VYxOAuiB4Yyqg9XX7Q64A7XBTYkCmekmBDxklxxOe1vaMoCSTjqtt6YU8nTrdHI4p0afU@fvLvR@s6NPw).  TIO takes about a minute for the last testcase.  My [results match](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/117637/seventy-seven-sevens#comment287866_117637) @Dennis's.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth --  <s>57</s> <s>51</s> <s>49</s> 42 bytes

```
FY}2eQKYJv*\7hQWJIqYJBW!%KJ=/KJ)=/JT)Iq1KY
```

[Try it](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=FY%7D2eQKYJv%2a%5C7hQWJIqYJBW%21%25KJ%3D%2FKJ%29%3D%2FJT%29Iq1KY&input=3%2C9999&debug=0)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! There are many shortcuts available, which can cut down your code by a lot of bytes. You can come to [our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) and ping me if you want to know more.

Comment: Unfortunately, your current program does not generate the correct results, namely that it includes `7` and `77` for your current input.

Comment: Ways to cut down bytes include: using `m` instead of `F` or `V` etc. (functional programming vs. execution control); using `hQ` instead of `@Q0`; using `eQ` instead of `@Q1`; using `i*hQ]7T` instead of the long for-loop to generate `777...7`.

Comment: @LeakyNun Thanks much for the suggestions and the chatroom link.  Also, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>94</s> <s>91</s> 88 bytes

```javascript
n=>l=>(X=[]).filter(g=(i,j=1,k)=>j>l|i[n]||(X[g(i+7,j,k)|g(i,j*i,-~k),k>1&&j]=j),l=g`7`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcpNCoMwEEDhfQ8iM20UbaRSyuQcggiK1ZAfkqLSVejV09pttt97enyP27Sq1547/5zjQtGRsCSgpa7HYlF2n1eQBIppqphBElrYoDrXhwBtJ0FdGqZ/IcjjOSuWfwwyI6os0z1pZJbk0AwYH6fJu83bubBewgIVQn1HTJXXPOErwq0sy8T54fW/xC8)

```javascript
n=>l=>         // input
(X=[]).filter( // X stores index=results
g=(i,j=1,k)=>  // recurse             Reuse of g for filter:
j>l|i[n]||     // out of range        49>1|49[n] (true)
(X[g(i+7,j,k)|g(i,j*i,-~k),k>1&&j]=j)
               // k<=1: X[false]=j, ignored
               // k>1: X[j]=j
,l=g`7`)       // First call [0/1]|[0/1]||1 ==1
```